# Google Analytics merging domain & subdomain index page info

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, subdirectory

I have set up a subdomain for the purpose of tracking the success of a magazine ad - the ad refers to the subdomain url - and I want to track the subdomain in Google Analytics.

The subdomain points to a subdirectory of the domain, and has just one page named index.php which is basically the same as the root directory's index.php.

I gave the subdomain's index.php the same analytics tracking code as the rest of the site in the hope that it would show up in analytics as a separate page, but instead visits to both the subdomain's index.php AND the domain's index.php are being merged and showing up as "/" (ie. root).

How can I separate these out?

What I need:

1. I need to see how many people are going specifically to the subdomain.
2. I need to see where they go from the subdomain landing page (all the links on the page lead to pages on the root level domain)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a secondary dimension of "Hostname" to your content reports to break out the subdomain. Then you can apply an advanced filter to the report to only show results where Hostname contains the subdomain you care about.

Then, you can choose the Navigation Summary view to see the next page paths.